# Error using `DropdownMenu` of material-ui with React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use `DropdownMenu` from http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu with this starter kit https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit. The dropdown menu appears but when I click it, it doesn't show its list.

Here are my steps:

1. `npm install --save material-ui`
2. Add the following lines to `render()` in `ContactPage.js`:

   ```
   render() {
     const title = 'Contact Us';
     this.context.onSetTitle(title);

     let menuItems = [
       { payload: '1', text: 'Never' },
       { payload: '2', text: 'Every Night' },
       { payload: '3', text: 'Weeknights' },
       { payload: '4', text: 'Weekends' },
       { payload: '5', text: 'Weekly' },
     ];
     const DropDownMenu = require('material-ui/lib/drop-down-menu');

     return (
       <div className="ContactPage">
         <div className="ContactPage-container">
           <h1>{title}</h1>
           <p>...</p>
           <DropDownMenu menuItems={menuItems}/>
           <AceEditor />
         </div>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```
3. `npm start`

Comment: Do you have more code you can show? I recommend checking the source code of how they do it in there docs - https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/components/pages/components/drop-down-menu.jsx http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu

Comment: Added more code. I think this guess is caused by **isomorphic** related settings in the starter kit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look at http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation?

You need to call
`injectTapEventPlugin();`